# GCC compiles program on Mac OS X but not on Ubuntu with clang

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, compilation, clang

I have tried to compile a file with the flags "-Wall -Wextra -Werror" on mac OS X at school and it works perfectly but when I go home and try the same thing on ubuntu it gives me this error:

```
tests/00_part1_ft_memset.spec.c: In function ‘unittest1’:
tests/00_part1_ft_memset.spec.c:9:12: error: ‘memset’ used with constant zero length parameter; this could be due to transposed parameters [-Werror=memset-transposed-args]
  mt_assert(memset(b1, 99, 0) == ft_memset(b1, 99, 0));
```

Why it doesn't work the same way on 2 different OS and is it possible to make my ubuntu react like an OS X? is there a config file for this?

Comment: Show your `tests/00_part1_ft_memset.spec.c`  file in your question

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Looks like the relevant part is already shown: `memset(b1, 99, 0)` is what causes the error.

Comment: And read documentation of [memset(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html)

Comment: Yes this is the part who generate this error but this code is an unit test and it work well on the mac osx :/ you can find the file here ->

https://github.com/yyang42/moulitest/blob/master/libft_tests/tests/00_part1_ft_memset.spec.c

Comment: @Nestoyeur It will likely also work on Ubuntu. The code is okay. It's the pickyness of the compilers that's different. You ask the compilers to be extremely picky, error out for just the slightest of lint. Now you have it. What does surprise you? That different compilers emit different warnings? Not surprising to anyone in the business.

Comment: The question is **not** why it appears "on one OS but not the other". The OS plays no role whatsoever. It is a matter of using different compilers. Stop confusing OSs and compilers.

Comment: Damn i finally find how work the Makefile (he call another Makefile) and the second one have the gcc command ! i swap it for clang and now it work so you was right @Jens its all about the compiler and not a config file or whatever ! thanks for help and keep singing :p

Comment: @Nestoyeur No problem, glad you know how to proceed. The next step on Stackoverflow is to *accept* an answer that helped you by clicking the check mark under the arrows to the left. That will earn you 2 credits.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does it not work the same way on two different OSs?

Because they use different compilers.

**Clang is not gcc**. While clang aims to be option-compatible with gcc, it also implements its own set of warnings.

You get what you asked for: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` enables a large set of warnings *and* makes them fatal.
 Your best bet is probably to selectively disable the memset-transposed-args warning. Or fix/adjust the code.

The error message points exactly to the problem, a 0 as the third arg of `memset`.

Comment: I use the exact same way to compile on the mac osx but this error dont appear. I will try to do as you say and disable some warning.

Comment: @Nestoyeur You should understand that compilers are allowed to warn about anything. If you deliberately make warnings fatal errors, then why does it surprise you that some other compiler chokes on something another compiler accepts? Would you expect a Microsoft compiler to accept the same options?

Answer (score 3):

I bet you don't really mean this right?

```
memset(b1, 99, 0);
```

that means you want to set the next 0 bytes to `(unsigned char)99`
that give you no value...

you probably mean:

```
memset(b1, 0, 99); // to set the next 99 bytes to the value 0
```

Comment: also since it returns its first argument the assertion seems a little strange

Comment: Not strange if you unit test an implementation of your own version of memset, called ft_memset, against the Standard C version.

Comment: Yes this is an unit test for my own implementation of memset (and other functions) for school project.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as Jens said, you're not dealing with the same compiler, so the functionnality can be different.

Thus, as a duoquadra, I understand what you're trying to achieve.

Try adding

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmemset-transposed-args"
```

In top of your test main, it should disable all the warning with this explicit name, and still compile with the -Wall -Wextra -Werror.

Comment: Hey duoquadra \o ;) after making it work on my computer i just realise that make the thing more strange than before now even if its work !

Comment: First the Makefile was using GCC commands on both my ubuntu and the OSX, but without the same result. Now i have edit the Makefile to use clang unstead of GCC and then it work in the same way than the OSX but this is definitly not the same compilers.

Comment: Strange, indeed.

Either way, I'd recommend using a VM if you want the same results you'd get in school.

Comment: Maybe they use an alias at school to force clang, like his ->
gcc () { clang $* }
Anyway i just add this one to my zshrc and tomorow i will take care of wich one is really used. If i cant be sure to have the same result on my laptop than school computer i will install OSX because i dont like the VM way